# How to Change search bar background color in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new in iphone, i want to change the search bar background to clear color how to change it to clear color. My code is:

```
UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 550, 330, 42)];
mySearchBar.delegate = self;
mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
mySearchBar.placeholder=@"Search here..";
    mySearchBar.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
[self.view  addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

Thanks in Advance:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because search bar have a default view and we remove this view then background color is clear

```
for (UIView *subview in mySearchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set using tint color, try to set tint color as per ur background color.

```
mySearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySearchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Instead of setting the tintColor set the backgroundColor of the searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

in ios 7 i did something like this.

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews.count >= 1) {
        for (UIView *subview in [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews]) {

            if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```